# Why is Aeson not pattern-matching Text?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, aeson

I am trying to pattern-match Text to aeson Value using the String constructor, and am running into compile errors. The following example program illustrates the issue I've been running into.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text
import qualified Data.Aeson

main = print $
  case ("here" :: Data.Text.Text) of
  (Data.Aeson.String x) -> "match"
  _                     -> "no match"
```

As shown I am trying to get the Text "here" to pattern-match into Aeson's 'String' Value constructor. I think that this program should pattern match the Text to Aeson String and print "match". But the program does not compile. Instead I get the following error:

```
$ ghc scratch.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( scratch.hs, scratch.o )

scratch.hs:9:4: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.Text.Text’
                  with actual type ‘Data.Aeson.Value’
    • In the pattern: Data.Aeson.String x
      In a case alternative: (Data.Aeson.String x) -> "match"
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘case ("here" :: Data.Text.Text) of {
           (Data.Aeson.String x) -> "match"
           _ -> "no match" }’
```

It says the pattern expected Text whereas the actual type was aeson Value. But it is clearly Text as marked by the type annotation ("here" :: Data.Text.Text). I don't understand why I am getting this error. Pattern-matching Text to aeson Value via the String constructor appears to be done in [this aeson tutorial](https://artyom.me/aeson), and I don't see why it does not also work in my example here.

Comment: There is indeed a type mismatch, and I'm quite sure you aren't doing the same thing as the tutorial. To see why, consider what the type of `Data.Aeson.String x` is.

Comment: Where does it appear to be done in that tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It says the pattern expected Text whereas the actual type was aeson Value. But it is clearly Text as marked by the type annotation

The value being matched is indeed of type `Text`. But the pattern you are matching against is not a pattern for the type `Text`; instead, it is a pattern for the type `Value`. You cannot match a value of one type against a pattern of another type, for obvious reasons.

There are many possible fixes, but it's difficult to choose one to suggest, because you have said little about what you are trying to do. *Possibly* you were intending to parse the `Text` into a `Value` and check which kind of value it was:

```
case decode (fromStrict (encodeUtf8 "\"match\"")) of
    Just (String x) -> "match"
    Just _ -> "no match"
    Nothing -> "invalid JSON"
```

However, I suspect that you are actually just misunderstanding how to use aeson, and should be writing a `FromJSON` instance (or using an existing one) rather than trying to muck about with `Text` values directly. For example, to parse a JSON value as `Text`, you might reuse the existing `FromJSON` instance for `Text` to write:

```
case decode "\"match\"" of
    Just v -> Data.Text.putStrLn v
    Nothing -> putStrLn "invalid JSON"
```

Again, both of these suggestions are pure speculation due to how light the question is on bigger-picture goals.